# welcome page after running dynamic web project

Tags: spring, jsf, tomcat7, welcome-file

I'm trying to let a welcome page displaying after running a dynamic web project.
When googling I found a lot of tutorials but I can't found the solution.
I share:

- The [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs1cG.png) of my project (I want that the page welcome.xhtml will displayed by default).
- The file `web.xml` is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" 
         version="3.0">
 <display-name>HiSpring</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 
 <context-param>
  <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
 </context-param>
 
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
 </context-param>
 
 <listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Once clicking on `HiSpring > Run As > Run on Server`, I should have
This url: `http://localhost:8080/HiSpring/faces/welcome.xhtml`. However, I got `http://localhost:8080/HiSpring/`.

Could you please tell me what I missed; Thanks in advance.

Comment: What technology are you using?

Comment: Hello @kometen, I'm using the technology JEE6.

Comment: Hi @Sofia, thank you. Please add them to the list in addition to welcome-file. Like java, servlets etc.

Comment: Hi @kometen, thanks a lot for your reply. If you don't mind, could you please give me an example?.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't. I don't know what technology you are using. Before asking you must supply adequate information before people can help you. Such as webserver, language etc.

Comment: Excuse me Sir for this ambiguity:The web server is Tomcat 7.0.  The language is Java. The frameworks are: JSF 2.2, Spring 4.0.2.

Comment: Awesome. Hope your issue will be solved, I don't know much though about spring nor JSF.

Comment: Some small things: On Tomcat7 using Spring, you are **not** running JEE6!. And JSF2.2 is not a framework, it is an api spec. Mojarra 2.2.x or MyFaces 2.2.x are the 'frameworks'

Answer (score 0):

According to your web.xml tomcat would look for `/welcome.xhtml` and has no clue that this might be in `/faces/welcome.xhtml`. The URL is fine (if welcome.xhtml is in `/`)

There might be a more elegant JSF version (I'm not much of a JSF guy) - some possible solutions that come to my mind would be

- map the faces servlet to `*.xhtml` do remove the `/faces/` part from path (you judge if this is proper JSF - comment if it's not and I'll remove this part)
- create a separate explicit redirection, e.g. through a (stupidly simple) index.html (of course, declare `index.html` as another welcome file) like the following sample:

```
<html>
 <head><title>Redirection</title>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=/faces/">
  <!-- 2 means 2 seconds delay. Change as you like -->
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>redirecting to application. <a href="/faces/">Click here if it doesn't work</a></p>
 </body>
</html>
```